# Im getting errors in spring boot when i try to login but i am able to save to my db using the same repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, repository

I am able to /save users to the MYSQL database using the UserRepository but when I try to /login with the same information I am getting a error which I cant figure out.

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''123!@#'' at line 1

Repository

```
package com.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.entity.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

    ///builds successfully but crashes saying sql syntax error, look up manual. Will allow me to save users to db
    @Query(value = "Select S from User S where S.email = ?1 and S.pass  ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    User login( String user, String pass);
    
    //doesnt build correct but is like my other repository
//  @Query("Select S from User S where S.email = ?1 and S.pass  ?2")
//  User login( String user, String pass);
}
```

User Controller

```
package com.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.entity.Saved;
import com.entity.User;
import com.repository.SavedRepository;
import com.repository.UserRepository;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    SavedRepository savedRepository;
    
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~user details group ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    //saving user details from new user login page
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save",
            consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            method=RequestMethod.POST
            )
    public void submitUserDetails(@RequestBody User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    
    //finds user details 
    @RequestMapping(value="/findUser",
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            method=RequestMethod.GET
            )
    private ResponseEntity<Optional<User>>findUser(String email){
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(email);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    //user Login details
    @RequestMapping(value="/login",
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            method=RequestMethod.POST
            )
    public ResponseEntity<User>login(@RequestBody User user){
        User userLogin = userRepository.login(user.getUser(), user.getPass());
        if(userLogin != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(userLogin, HttpStatus.OK);
        }else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
```

I have tried using native vs Jpla queries and parametrized them. I'm not exactly sure what else to do.

Comment: presumably you need an `=` between `S.pass` and `?2`.

Comment: This was an error but it wasnt catching it yet. When i run the native spring successfully builds but when i sent info i get an: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'S' in 'field list'. My saved repository is using a very similar query but it works.

Comment: Please read some SQL tutorials. Presumably the `User` table doesn't have a field named `S`. List the fields you want to retrieve (or use `*`) in your query.

Comment: using spring jpa with queries it is required to have the "S" or another placeholder in there. With nativeQuery=true i guess i didnt need it. My problem ended up being in my User @Entity class. It was confused with my naming assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using native query you can opt for custom methods that you can create in Spring Data JPA.
Simply add below code in your UserRepository

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
   User findByEmailAndPass(String email, String password);
}
```

You can get more details: https://javatute.com/jpa/how-to-write-custom-method-in-repository-in-spring-data-jpa/
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details

Comment: No shot on that. im getting a error code of : org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ApplicationConfig: Could not create query for public abstract com.entity.User com.repository.

Comment: UserRepository.findByEmailAndPass(java.lang.String,java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.entity.User com.repository.UserRepository.findByEmailAndPass(java.lang.String,java.lang.String); No property 'email' found for type 'User'

Comment: Can you share your User entity?